# Rails 3.1: Upgrading caused my link_to path routes to break?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have some routes that worked fine in my Rails 3.0.7 app prior to upgrading to 3.1.

```
# routes.rb
resources :chapters do
  resources :cards
end

resources :cards
```

With some controller code like this:

```
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    @card = @chapter.cards.new   # for "new card" form thats displayed on this same page
    respond_with(@chapter)
  end
```

With a fairly typical scaffold generated view with links:

```
<% @chapter.cards.each do |card| %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_card_path(card) %>
<% end %>
```

Now, if I try to pull it up in the browser, I get errors like this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cards", :id=>#<Card id: nil, side1: nil, side2: nil, chapter_id: 6, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

It's showing the ID being `nil` which isn't true because I can display the other values on this record.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try with `edit_chapter_card_path(card)` in the erb?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also, that's not the route I was trying to create. I originally wrote it to go to `/cards/123/edit` instead of nesting it.

Comment: However, when I commented out the line where I call `@chapter.cards.new` it seems to work again. It looks like the problem has to do with the fact that I'm calling `@chapter.cards.new` which (I'm assuming) is adding a blank card model to the top of the `@chapter.cards` stack. Not sure if this is a feature or a bug! What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something changed with the way nested models work in Rails 3.1. From what I can tell, calling `@chapter.cards.new` adds a blank card model to the top of the `@chapter.cards` stack, which it didn't used to to. So instead of calling `@chapter.cards.new` and iterating over the `@chapter.cards` array in the same action, I will have to keep these separate:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
  @card = Card.new
  @card.chapter_id = @chapter.id
  respond_with(@chapter)
end
```